# Microsoft team ui modification

Tags: user-interface, microsoft-teams, zoom-sdk, teams-toolkit, meeting-request

I want to make changes in the ui like in the picture. Want to add card like that is that possible to modify the team ui?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7OK5.jpg)

I'm looking in teams tool kit

Comment: Could you please elaborate your issue in detail? Where you want to add card and which card you want to add here?

Comment: I just want to add empty space.I uploaded a edited pictute Iwant exactly like that. Is that possible?

Comment: For an adaptive card or any other card, do you want to add the empty space?

Comment: not adaptive just a plane space

Comment: Do you want to change the default meeting UI and add empty space there?

Comment: Do you want to change the default meeting UI and add empty space there?